# Access indexed rows in a python list (similar to Matlab cell array)

Tags: python

I have a bunch of different matrices of different size stored on disk. I need to process them in python in a fast way so I loaded every matrix into memory and stored them in a python list.
I want to select a subset of these list entries via a vector of row indices (equivalent to selecting cells in a cell array in Matlab) is that possible in python?

A Matlab example would look like this:

```
allData = cell(100,1); % This cell array contains my different matrices of variable sizes
rowIndices = randi(100,10,1);

selectedData = allData(rowIndices,1);
```

How can I do the same in python?

```
allData # In python this is a list of "numpy.ndarray"s
rowIndices = random.sample(range(1, numRows), batch_size)
batch_data = allData[rowIndices]
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach would be to use a list comprehension:

```
batch_data = [allData[i] for i in rowIndices]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [NumPy matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html). It looks like its [take()](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.take.html#numpy.matrix.take) method could be helpful in this case.